# Get Populate data from looping vb.net

Tags: vb.net

for example, i get 3 data from looping 111 222 333
and then i want to  return value like :

> '111','222','333'

so, how to combine and complete my looping with `substring (')` and `(,)`.

because I have Execute a query with condition  `where in ('111','222','333')`.

This is my code in vb.net :

```
For Each grv As GridViewRow In gridDisplayGRN.Rows
    Dim chk As CheckBox = CType(grv.FindControl("ChkSelect"), CheckBox)
    If chk.Checked = True Then
        Dim p As New PengirimanDetail
        p.KodePenerimaan = grv.Cells(2).Text.Trim()
        Dim parm = p.KodePenerimaan  => first looping get 111 and next looping 222 333
        Dim data = "'" + parm + "'"  => '111'
        Dim return = '111','222','333' ???
    End If
Next
```

Please give me the true code,Thanks...

Comment: What is the raw data? Can you use Rawdata.Split(" ")?

Comment: Second - hardcoding parameters in the sql query - is a bad practice - even thay are numbers. Use SQL parameters or Sql Parameter which used table type if those numbers are too much

Comment: The true code? `Dim return =`?! You have been a member of SO for over 1 year?! I am speechless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this issue, I will show you one one of it.

1. You have to declare a variable to store your result string outside of the loop. Otherwise you overwrite it in each step, here in a list.
2. Inside the loop you collect all KodePenerimaan strings in the variable created in 1., here via String.Concat.
3. After the loop you concat all collected strings to your desired format, here via String.Join.

   ```
   Dim parms as new List(Of String) 'collection for KodePenerimaans
   For Each grv As GridViewRow In gridDisplayGRN.Rows
       Dim chk As CheckBox = CType(grv.FindControl("ChkSelect"), CheckBox)
       If chk.Checked = True Then
          Dim p As New PengirimanDetail
          p.KodePenerimaan = grv.Cells(2).Text.Trim()
          parms.Add(String.Concat("'", p.KodePenerimaan, "'")) 'Add current KodePenerimaan to list
       End If
   Next
   Dim result as String = String.Empty
   If parms.Count > 0 Then
      result = String.Join(",", parms) 'Join to "'111','222','333'"
   End If
   return result
   ```